# Send Spline Attribute from Geometry Nodes to Shader

Tags: shaders, bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I am currently trying to get into Geometry Nodes.
Right now I have a problem: In my scene there is a Curve object with 3 splines. It is important that the splines are not created in the geometry nodes, but already exist.
Now I would like to send a separate spline as attribute for shading, so that the splines can get different colors. But I just can't get this to work.

My attempt looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: I am sorry but I don’t know what attribute you want that should change what value in your shader?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, indexes start with 0, so first spline will be #0 and #1.

Second, if you are using **capture attribute**, set the type to "spline" (not "point")

3rd, index in **spline parameter** returns indexes of points in the spline, not useful then you want to get index of spline, use **Index** node instead.

4th, Capture attribute should be connected to the output before curve to mesh node. In that case, you will get the indexes of spline before they will be converted to mesh.

And at last but not least, you have to make an attribute to save data:

[image]

Then you will be able to use it in shader editor.

This is a final setup:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. But how can I select an index? I have now changed Capture Attributes to Spline, but I can't isolate a spline with the shading.... I thought the Math Node with Less Than would select the index under 2.

Comment: I see now, it's because capture attribute is not connected to output. Put it before convert to mesh

Comment: But when I do that, the mesh around the curve also disappears. It is also not possible to have 2 outputs.

Comment: @Andi I have updated the answer.

Comment: Yep, that's it! Thank you very much. Why the index node is used here instead of the spline parameter is a mystery to me. But I'm glad it works now.

Comment: @Andi  spline parameter gives you an index of point restarted from 0 in each spline. Using capture attribute with spline setting will give you 0 every time.